# JSON from API call not mapping to component correctly

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services

I'm trying to map JSON returned by an api call to a property in my component but for some reason, the nested structures become inaccessible once I try to access them from the component.

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { UserData } from './user-data';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  private dataUrl = 'https://habitica.com/export/userdata.json';
  private userId = '[removed]';
  private apiToken = '[removed]';

  getData (): Observable<UserData> {
    let headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('x-api-user', this.userId);
    headers.append('x-api-key', this.apiToken);

    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl, { headers: headers })
                    .map(this.extractData)
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    console.log(res);
    let body = res.json();
    console.log(body);
    return body || { };
  }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { UserData } from './user-data';
// Add the RxJS Observable operators we need in this app.
import './rxjs-operators';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  providers: [ DataService ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  data: UserData;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
        data => this.data = data
    )
   }

}
```

I can hit the right data from the service in `extractData` but once it gets mapped, I lose all my nested json structures.

Edit:

Turns out I can access them by using `{{ data?.tasks?.dailys | json }}`

Is that just because the data hasn't loaded when I first try to access it? Is this the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, this should help :

Before response of the API is received, `data.tasks` is undefined, and hence `data.tasks.dailys` is undefined. So whenever you are using it without check you get an error at start.

you can use `ngIf` attribute to check if that key is available and then only execute `data.tasks.dailys`.

```
<div *ngIf='data && data.tasks && data.tasks.dailys'>
  {{data.tasks.dailys}}
</div>
```

This way `data.tasks.dailys` will be executed only when its present, i.e after the API response has been received.